# How do I set the access data of my database depending on the port number

Tags: php, git, xampp

I have a local environment and a live website, but these two environments use different databases.

I would check if the website is local by checking if the `top-level-domain == "localhost"`. Or is there a better way?

But the real problem is that my local database has a different port number than that of my employee and since we work via Git, the access data for him are wrong. How can I adapt the configuration file so that the local access is correct with him and with me?

We work with xampp.

Comment: What I usually do is to have the database credentials in a config file that's gitignored (you should try and avoid having credentials and other sensitive data in your git repo). Then on each environment, you can create the config file with the credentials that fits that environment.